# SQL Query: LEFT Join only returning intersection

Tags: sql, left-join

I've been struggling with what I believed is an easy SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
  resource.firstname, 
  resource.lastname, 
  resource.fte, 
  project.name as project_name, 
  role.name as role_name, 
  assignment.startdate, 
  assignment.enddate, 
  assignment.numberofdaysperweek
FROM 
  resource
LEFT JOIN assignment ON resource.id = assignment.resource_id AND assignment.enddate < now()
LEFT JOIN project ON project.id = assignment.project_id 
LEFT JOIN role ON role.id = assignment.role_id
```

So I have 4 tables in this Query: `resources` are `assigned` to `projects` and are given a specific `role` for that project.

The problem with this query is that it will return data for any resource + any resource with an "expired" assignment (assignment.enddate < now()). However I need this condition to be applied only to the LAST assignment for that resource. **Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?**

Comment: How do *you* define "the LAST assignment"? Is it also based on `enddate`? `startdate`? Some other column not mentioned?

Comment: Well, there can't be two assignments for the same resource overlapping so, last enddate, last startdate, it's the same. Latest assignment entry for a resource is also the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit your assignments to only the latest assignment for each resource, you need to find the latest start date for each resource_id and `INNER JOIN` back to the assignment table;

```
SELECT  assignment.*
FROM    assignment
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  assignment.resource_id, 
                    MAX(assignment.StartDate) AS StartDate
            FROM    assignment
            GROUP BY assignment.resource_id
        ) MaxAssignment
            ON assignment.resource_id = MaxAssignment.resource_id
            AND assignment.StartDate = MaxAssignment.StartDate;
```

Since you only want to `LEFT JOIN` to this, you then need to move the whole of the above into a subquery and `LEFT JOIN` the entire subquery back to main query:

```
SELECT  resource.firstname, 
        resource.lastname, 
        resource.fte, 
        project.name as project_name, 
        role.name as role_name, 
        assignment.startdate, 
        assignment.enddate, 
        assignment.numberofdaysperweek
FROM    resource
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  assignment.*
            FROM    assignment
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  assignment.resource_id, 
                                MAX(assignment.StartDate) AS StartDate
                        FROM    assignment
                        GROUP BY assignment.resource_id
                    ) MaxAssignment
                        ON assignment.resource_id = MaxAssignment.resource_id
                        AND assignment.StartDate = MaxAssignment.StartDate
        ) assignment
            ON resource.id = assignment.resource_id 
            AND assignment.enddate < now()
        LEFT JOIN project 
            ON project.id = assignment.project_id 
        LEFT JOIN role 
            ON role.id = assignment.role_id;
```

If I have mis-understood your interpretation of "last" assignment per resource, you may need to tinker with the aggergate inside the subquery `MaxAssignmen` and the inner join back to `assignments`, but the same principal should apply.

**EDIT**

For some reason I had assumed this was MySQL, but the error message in the comment below looks more like Postgresql, in which case you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to limit it to only the last assignment for each resource:

```
SELECT  resource.firstname, 
        resource.lastname, 
        resource.fte, 
        project.name as project_name, 
        role.name as role_name, 
        assignment.startdate, 
        assignment.enddate, 
        assignment.numberofdaysperweek
FROM    resource
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ResourceID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) RN
            FROM    assignment
        ) assignment
            ON resource.id = assignment.resource_id 
            AND RN = 1
            AND assignment.enddate < now()
        LEFT JOIN project 
            ON project.id = assignment.project_id 
        LEFT JOIN role 
            ON role.id = assignment.role_id;
```

Comment: Using your select, I get:
ERREUR:  entrée manquante de la clause FROM pour la table « assignment »
LINE 23:   ) assigment ON resource.id = assignment.resource_id AND as...

Translating as:
ERROR: missing entry in FROM clause for the table "assignment"

Comment: I misspelled the alias `assignment` on the subquery. I have corrected this.

Comment: My bad, I thought I had checked them all. Thanks, it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support the `row_number()` function.  With such a function, you can handle this as:

```
SELECT 
  resource.firstname, 
  resource.lastname, 
  resource.fte, 
  project.name as project_name, 
  role.name as role_name, 
  assignment.startdate, 
  assignment.enddate, 
  assignment.numberofdaysperweek
FROM 
  resource
LEFT JOIN (select a.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by resource_id order by enddate) as seqnum
           from assignment a
           where assignment.enddate < now()
          ) assignment
     ON resource.id = assignment.resource_id AND seqnum = 1
LEFT JOIN project ON project.id = assignment.project_id 
LEFT JOIN role ON role.id = assignment.role_id;
```

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential number to the assignments within each value of `resource_id` (`partition by resource_id`).  These are then ordered so that the one with the latest `enddate` gets a value of 1 (`order by enddate`).